# Extracting some pattern using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex pattern that will match a "digit~digit~string~sentence". eg `14~742091~065M998~P E ROUX 214`. I've come up with the following so far:

`String regex= "\\d+~?\\d+~?\\w+~?"`

How do I extract the sentence after the last `~`?

Comment: Why not just `s.split("~")`?

Comment: OR. Try this regex `(?<=~)[^~]*$`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Capturing Groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
\d+~?\d+~?\w+~(.*)
```

`group(1)` contains the part you want.

Another solution is using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String[] splitted = myString.split("~");
String res = splitted[splitted.length() - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups `()`, as demonstrated in this pattern: `"\\d+~\\d+~\\w+~(.*)"`. Note that you don't need the greedy quantifier `?`.

```
String input = "14~742091~065M998~P E ROUX 214";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+~\\d+~\\w+~(.*)");
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+~){2}\\w+~(.*)"); (would also work)

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Prints:

`P E ROUX 214`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `( )` to extract the output you want,
for more details see [here](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Answer (score 0):

```
.*~(.*)$
```

This simple regex should work for you.

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/12)

Answer (score 0):

try the regexp below, the sentence only contains alphanumeric and spaces

> ^\d+~\d+~\w+~[\w\s]+